# JSON numbers formatted with commas

Tags: json, angular6

How can I take some JSON data that contains a number and insert commas in the numbers? 
Example: I fetch some JSON data from a url and can display it, it contains a number. let's say 100000. (100,000). It doesn't have a comma to better show **100,000**.

language used: Angular 6 (Typescript)

Comment: What exactly does your JSON data look like? Is it a JSON object or a Number?

Comment: I guess it's just a number. here's a sample: `{
    "playerstats": {
    "stats": [
    {
    "name": "deaths",
    "value": 100000
    }
        ]
    }

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, pick your poison:

[Intl Number Format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat();
formatter.format(number);
```

Reg-ex:

```
function addThousandsSeparator(n) {
    return n.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
}
```

[Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)

```
numeral(number).format('0,0')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Number.toLocaleString("en-US")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) should insert commas, the way you want it to.

```
Number("100000").toLocaleString("en-US")
// "100,000"
```

Comment: Your solution is also very good! Thank you for the help. My code:
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BEipc96R)